# Installing SQL Server Express 2008 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Can I install SQL Server Express 2008 on a Windows Server 2008 or should I stick with the SQL Server Express 2005?

Answer (score 6):

On the [download page for SQL Server 2008 (with tools)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7522A683-4CB2-454E-B908-E805E9BD4E28&displaylang=en), it lists these supported operating systems: Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2; **Windows Server 2008**; Windows Vista; Windows Vista Service Pack 1; Windows XP Service Pack 2; Windows XP Service Pack 3

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it runs without difficulty and is painless to install, especialy if you use the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx), which can also install Management Studio Express to help administer the database.

Comment: Up vote this a 1000 times!  Or else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677435/invoke-or-begininvoke-cannot-be-called-on-a-control-until-the-window-handle-has

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. The [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx) lists all of the different versions of Windows Server 2008 supported.

Why would you assume this to be impossible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install either 2005 express or 2008 express.
Or you could install both.